# calculating days Left between two dates excluding national Holidays in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to calculate Days left between two dates excluding Holidays and WeekDays (Sat,Sun) using jquery UI Datepicker.

I have succeeded in calculating remaining days excluding Weekdays but just stuck over excluding national Holidays. How to exclude these National Holidays while calculating remaining Days.

here is code :

```
var natDays=[]; 
natDays[0]=[1, 27];
natDays[1]=[2, 6];
natDays[2]=[3, 17];
natDays[3]=[2, 7]; 
function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
            && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
            return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
    } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}
function excludeWeekDaysOrHolidays(startDate, endDate) {
    if (endDate < startDate){
        return 0;
    }
    // Calculate days between dates
    var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
    startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);  // Start just after midnight
    endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);  // End just before midnight
    var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
    var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);
    // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
    var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
    var days = days - (weeks * 2);
    // Handle special cases
    var startDay = startDate.getDay();
    var endDay = endDate.getDay();
    // Remove weekend not previously removed.   
    if (startDay - endDay > 1)         
    days = days - 2;      
    // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
    if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)
        days = days - 1  
    // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
    if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)
        days = days - 1  
    //check if National Holiday is in between two dates
    if (noWeekendsOrHolidays(date)[0]) {
        days=nationalDays(date);

    }   
    return days;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Also, i am trying following code :

```
diff=endDate-startDate;
var holi=new Array("02-25-2013","05-22-2013","06-28-2013");
p=0;
hcnt=0;
while(p<holi.length)
{
    holiday=new Date(holi[p]);
    //alert(holiday);
    if(diff>holiday-startDate)
        hcnt++;
        //alert(hcnt);
        p++;
    }
```

Holiday is returning "Invalid Date" error. hcnt is always showing 0.

Comment: In which part of the first code should be the second code(solution)? or can you update your question with the solution in the code. Thanks

Comment: Or you can post it in a fiddle? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Date("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

instead of "MM-DD-YYYY"...

In your case:

```
var holi = new Array("2013-02-25", "2013-05-22", "2013-06-28");
```